# Modular exponentiation overflows when using multiple of two uint_32 numbers

Tags: c++, c++11, rsa, modular-arithmetic

I am trying to implement  RSA key signing and verifying. 
I am making use of the modular exponentiation where I am encountering errors possibly due to integer overflow.

```
uint64_t modmult(uint64_t a,uint64_t b,uint64_t mod)
{

    if (a == 0 || b < mod / a)
        return ((uint64_t)a*b)%mod;
    uint64_t sum;
    sum = 0;
    while(b>0)
    {
        if(b&1)
            sum = (sum + a) % mod;
        a = (2*a) % mod;
        b>>=1;
    }
    return sum;
}
uint64_t modpow( uint64_t a,uint64_t b,uint64_t mod)
{

    uint64_t product,pseq;
    product=1;
    pseq=a%mod;
    while(b>0)
    {
        if(b&1)
            product=modmult(product,pseq,mod);
        pseq=modmult(pseq,pseq,mod);
        b>>=1;
    }
    return product;
}
```

The function call

```
long long d = 2897297195663230443;
uint64_t n = 10136926879504331723;
modpow(1233,d,n);
```

The `n` is a multiple of two unsigned uint32_t prime numbers `(4063800743,2494444861)` the modular exponentiation
the result is `3148683887780272464`, but it should be `9640529604970470922`

Basically, this implementation is not handling unsigned 64 integer values of `n` well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that, due to the modulus being > 2<sup>63</sup>, the `a + sum` step in your `modmult` routine might overflow, losing a bit.  The same might happen with `2*a`.

One way to fix the problem would be to add a `modadd` routine:

```
uint64_t modadd(uint_64_t a, uint64_t b, uint64_t mod) {
    if (a >= mod) a %= mod;    // precondition -- might not be needed if the caller can guarentee it.
    if (b >= mod) b %= mod;    // precondition -- might not be needed if the caller can guarentee it

    a += b;
    if (a >= mod || a < b) a -= mod;
    return a;
}
```

Then, use `modadd(sum, a, mod)` and `modadd(a, a, mod)` in your `modmult` routine.

Comment: @DeepakTivari: [modular multiplicative inverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_multiplicative_inverse)